# GetType of Values in DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, gettype

I've been working on a project which has a Function of reading Data from a DataTable and returning it as a list. I made specific statements over some rows to get the data I want. 
Little problem is, my entity "Number" is declared As an Integer and in the DataTable I do have some String values which leads the function to crash. Do any of you guys has an Idea about how I can check which Data Type the row "Number" has and if it's not an Integer to just leave it out?

My function looks like this:

```
 Public Function LiefereAlleRechte(ByVal dt As DataTable) As ICollection(Of Recht) Implements IBenutzerInfoServiceUtil.LiefereAlleRechte
    If dt Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("DataTable can't be empty", "dt")
    End If

    Dim query = From dr As DataRow In dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "Name", "Number")

    Dim coll As ICollection(Of Recht) = New List(Of Recht)
    For Each row In query
        Dim recht As Recht = New Recht()

            With recht
            .Name = row.Item("Name")
            .Nummer = row.Item("Number")
                coll.Add(recht)
        End With

    Next

    Return coll
End Function
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where did the data come from?  There are easier ways to get data into a typed list.  `how I can check which Data Type the row "Number" ` Number would appear to be a column not row.  `datatable,columns(n).DataType` will tell you the type

Comment: It sounds like your "Number" column is a string, so you could try something like `If IsNumeric(row.Item("Number")) Then .Nummer = row.Item("Number")`, but I would recommend that you turn `Option Strict On` and explicitly convert to the appropriate type (e.g. `If IsNumeric(row.Field(Of String)("Number")) Then .Nummer = CInt(row.Field(Of String)("Number")`).

Comment: Just a warning about my previous comment - `IsNumeric` will return `True` for decimal numbers too (`IsNumeric("123.4")` returns `True`)... `Int32.TryParse` may be a better option, depending on your datatypes.

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for the answers. I've tried it with **parse** and **tryparse** yesterday and it didn't work. So, as I only have Strings or Integers (no decimals) in that column, and I only need the Integers, this worked just fine:  `If IsNumeric(row.Item("Number")) Then` . Thanks @Mark!